# IFRAME tiff image print doesnt print full image

Tags: javascript, iframe, printing, tiff

I am facing one issue regarding IFRAME print functionality.
Tiff image is assigned to IFRAME and its rendered properly. I can see full image.
Now when i am giving print from javascript, 
1) I am not getting page orientation (either portrait or landscape)
2) By default it treat as portrait and not able to get full image print.

This is my Code:-

```
function framePrint() 
         {
                var iframe = $('.Iframe1');
                iframe[0].contentWindow.focus();
                iframe[0].contentWindow.print();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set any preferences with window.print(), so you can't solve this problem with javascript, unfortunately. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.print

What you could do is rotate the image sideways so that it will print in landscape mode when it's print out in portrait mode. You can either set this as the image, or rotate the existing image with jQuery.